# spdecode in simple-pt responds with 'error trace stream does not match query' Intel Processor Trace

Tags: debugging, x86, intel, trace, intel-pmu

I am a newbie using Intel PT for the trace.
I have read Intel PT manual and started to use it with simple-pt to understand how Intel PT works.

`sptcmd` command in simple-pt works and generates `ptout.N` with following command.

```
sudo ./sptcmd -c ls ls
```

When I use sptdecode as follows:
`sudo ./sptdecode --sideband ptout.sideband --pt ptout.0`

I get the following response:

> TIME      DELTA         INSNs   OPERATION
>   50:0: error trace stream does not match query
>   50: sync forward: trace stream does not match query

I have tried with boot argument of `nopti` as mentioned on simple-pt Git repo.

Additional information about setup which maybe relevant:
Compiled and built simple-pt from Git repo https://github.com/andikleen/simple-pt.
Using libipt by building from latest Git repo https://github.com/01org/processor-trace.
Using Ubuntu - 16.04

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you run the command to create the `ptout.*` files?  The github readme shows `sptcmd  -c tcall taskset -c 0 ./tcall` as an example.  Include your exact command in the question to make this a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you Peter for feedback. I ran the trace for `ls` command as edited above and same is mentioned in another example on Github.